# How to edit a CLR function in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clr, sqlclr

In a current project there are some user defined CLR aggregate function.

Now I have to edit it. How can I do this?

And how to fine where .dll file is saved?

Is there any way to check what is written in the function from sql server?

Comment: Your mention of a ".dll" makes it likely that you actually want to edit the CLR assembly, rather than the function definition which wraps it. To do this you'll need to amend the source code and recompile it to produce a new dll which you can then use to replace the existing assembly. There's no way to inspect the source of the assembly from within SQL Server; you'll need access to the source of the .Net project from which the assembly was originally built. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for some background to SQL CLR.

Comment: How to find the assembly from .net as i dont have any idea where it was saved

Comment: It's unlikely anybody here can help you with that, unless they actually worked on your project.

Comment: is it possible to know what is written inside the function?

Comment: You could export the assembly from the db to a file (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3126/exporting-clr-assemblies-from-sql-server-back-to-dll-files), then use a decompiler to examine the contents

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the query select * from sys.assembly_modules to get the list of assemblies. You can view the function if you expand the Database --> Programmability --> Functions --> Aggregate Functions

Comment: You will be getting "Script Function as" option under the Aggregate Functions. You can modify and alter the same.